# Calling postgres table disconnects Flask connection

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I have python 2.7.6, flask 0.12.2

Here is my models.py file

```html
import flask_sqlalchemy, app
import os

# app.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')

db = flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(app.app)

class Message(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) # key
    message = db.Column(db.String(200))
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    pic = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    
    def __init__(self, m, n, p):
        self.message = m
        self.name = n
        self.pic = p
    
    def __repr__(self): # what's __repr__?
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.message, self.pic, self.name)
        
#if __name__ == "__main__":
#    messageQuery = Message.query.all()
#    print messageQuery
```

In my app.py file, I import models, and when I try to use

```
messageQuery = models.Message.query.all()
```

the Flask connection disconnects. Any idea why?

Comment: How do you know that it disconnects? Any python exception, postgres logs?

Comment: There is a flask function that runs on disconnect, and the sid that connects disconnects when the db connection tries to initiate. The postgres logs are empty.

Comment: Sqlalchemy uses connection pool, and has some logic to timeout connections. Flask_sqlalchemy uses this pool and returns connection to pool on app context exit. My first advice: turn on sqlalchemy logs and see that's happening there. Log configuration doc: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#configuring-logging